# ASP.NET Roles not working in deployed ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-membership

I have published and deployed an ASP.NET MVC application that uses the Roles feature of ASP.NET authentication. On my development machine, Roles work fine - but **on my server**, to which I've transferred the build, the entire database (schema, data, and users), and with full permissions, **Roles don't work**.

Here is the line where my code crashes:

```
var exists = Roles.RoleExists("Administrator");
```

For some reason, such Roles queries aren't working, but `System.Web.Security.Roles.Enabled` returns `true` and `System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider` is set properly.

What gives?

Comment: And with what particular exception does the code crash?

Comment: What exception is thrown? What about connection strings?

Comment: @mellamokb: to be honest, I'm not quite sure. I haven't found a way to debug on my server, so I'm just getting the standard "Error" view. The reason I know that it's this line that is causing the trouble is because I have separated it out into a separate method and have found that the crash happens there. Any ideas on how to debug further?

Comment: @kubal5003: see my above comment regarding the exception. about connection strings: the ones I have set work, because the other components that use my DB work.

Comment: @Maxim: To see errors on the server, temporarily set `<configuration debug="true">` in your `web.config` configuration settings.  This would be in the `<system.web>` section.

Comment: @mellamokb: it's already set to that...

Comment: @Maxim: OK. So when we ask what exception is thrown, we want to see the output of that error page. I.e., add to your question the Error message and the stack trace.  That can help immensely in diagnosing errors.

Comment: @mellamokb: I understand what you're asking, but for some reason, I'm not able to get an error page. This is a recurring problem I've had with debugging ASP.NET MVC, because some internal errors result in only the default error view being visible, even if debug is set to true, customErrors are disabled, etc.

Comment: On some hostings there are other ways to see errors - eg. on mine (webio.pl) errors are visible in the control panel, while on others I've seen eg. special folders with log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, and it turned out to be unrelated to ASP.NET. The problem, which I found in my SQL logs, was that **my SQL user did not have the EXECUTE permission for the database**. All it took was a simple query:

```
CREATE ROLE db_executor;
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor;
```

Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to take a guess, authentication is set up incorrectly on IIS on the server you have deployed to. Most likely, you used the built in developer server to develop and you have now deployed to a server that has default settings in IIS.

Comment: Open the IIS management console on the server (or locally and attach to IIS on the server in question). Click on the website in question and go to authentication. I would guess you need to enable windows authentication to get a user that can be compared against roles, but I don't have the time to do a quick test right now.

Comment: You can use CurrentContext to get user and identity information. Set up a temporary page and see what user is used locally and what user on the server. You may have to turn off anon access on the server (not sure, as I don't know your setup); it is done in the same place.